# IIS rewrite to CustomError 403 not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

So I'm trying to catch all query strings and return a 403.
I've got the following rule in my web.config (using URL Rewrite module)

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="PREVENT QUERYSTRING" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="([?&amp;=]+)" />
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Unallowed" statusDescription="Unallowed" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Then I type in my browser

> http://site.local?test=test

and I don't get no 403.
Can someone tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match the query string and not the request URL. Like this

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="PREVENT QUERYSTRING" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Unallowed" statusDescription="Unallowed" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([?&amp;=]+)" />
                    </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```